# Using OAuth2 to permit users to authorize as a global user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-admin-sdk

Apologies for the oddly worded title, however I could not come up with a better one.

My application should be able to perform a limited set of actions on an Enterprise Google Apps system. Users submit requests to the application, the application interprets these requests and then makes requests to Google resources as necessary.The point is that users, who normally do not have permissions to access/modify the google apps resources, will be able to use this application to do so in the limited ways that it allows.

My problem lies in the apparent fact that the OAuth2.0 authorization flow seems designed to allow third party client applications to authorize themselves as the *user* and access/modify the *user's* google resources, rather than a global administrator's. In other words, a normal API key type deal. Unfortunately it seems that Google's AdminSDK will only work with OAuth2 authorization.

Is there a way to use Google's AdminSDK API with OAuth2 (permanent access token, maybe? API key?) to do what I want? Or is there a different API I should be trying? The now-deprecated Provisioning API seemed to be able to do this.

I feel like there should be a way for the application to just pull something out of a `secrets.json` or `secrets.yml`, include that in the API authorization request and have Google servers recognize and grant access to the application without the user ever needing to see what's going on.

For the record I'm using Ruby on Rails, though I don't think that affects the question very much.

Comment: You can use API key when you no need to access private user data. I don't think you can use API key with Admin sdk, as it involves accessing user data. So, you should go with Oauth 2.0 authentication. check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing

Comment: But is it possible to use OAuth to allow a user to do something beyond their authorization level with the API? For instance, can a (normal) user use the API to execute administrative tasks? It seems to me they will not be able to since they are authorized as themselves